# How to display error message when two fields are empty javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to display error messgae using javascript or jquery only when both the feilds are empty. For example a user can either enter Zipcode or select a state from dropdown. If the user doesnot select any one of those then the error should be displayed.

Comment: that's actually a bit complicated, how well do you know JS?

Comment: make a new window popup that says your message.

Comment: Can you update what is the actual Scenario regarding 2 fields ? What are the two fields  ?

Comment: please provide your some code

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to only show one of the input fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value of the elements by `document.getElementById("id").value`

```js
function Validate() {
  var zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
  var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
  
  if(zip == "" && state == 0) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Error message";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="zip">
<select id="state">
  <option value="0">Select a state</option>
  <option value="State 1">State 1</option>
  <option value="State 2">State 2</option>
  <option value="State 3">State 3</option>
  <option value="State 4">State 4</option>
</select>
<p id="error"></p>
<button onclick="Validate()">Submit</button>
```

Note : You can disable an element when the other is selected using `document.getElementById("id").disabled = true;`